# Get mouse cooridinates relative to svg element

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using `GSAP` to tween an svg circle `x-position` to the mouse clientX.

Circle is on the left side of the page, and everything works fine when I click near the circles origin. But as I click more to the right of the circle, the circle tween ends up farther and farther to the right of where the mouse was clicked.

This is the code I'm using for the final position of the circle after the tween.

```
var offSet = sliderLine.getBoundingClientRect().x;
var newx = e.clientX - offSet;
TweenMax.to(sliderKnob, 0, {x:newx})
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question. The code you have currently added is not complete, we cannot run it and see what you see.

Comment: Robert thank you so much! While stripping out code to get to the relevant code to post, the problem went away... there was nothing wrong with the code I originally posted. I haven't found the problem yet but at least I know where to look. Thanks again!